# undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass ruby beginner

Tags: ruby

Here is some code:

```
print "What is your name?"
userinput = gets.chomp.downcase!
if userinput.include? "s"
  print "I found it"
else
  print "found nothing"
end
```

It gives the error: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

but when I change it to:

```
print "What is your name?"
userinput = gets.chomp
userinput.downcase!
if userinput.include? "s"
  print "I found it"
else
  print "found nothing"
end
```

It works just fine. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`downcase!` returns `nil` when there is nothing to downcase. If you reassign that to `userinput`, then `userinput` can become `nil` as in your first example. If you use `downcase` instead, then the error will go away. In your second example, you are not reassigning the result of `downcase!` to `userinput`, so `userinput` is not overwritten as `nil`.